# Use $each to search multiple rows of arrays in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are trying to create an easy "chat-bot" to interact with which will give you an answer based on keywords in your search query.

Example: You type in "Where is the closest bar?" and the bot will give you the answer "Its here bla bla bla".

We are trying to do this through storing the possible keywords and answers through arrays. We managed to run through one array but are not able to run trough them all to see if there is any keywords that fits to another option. How do we do that?

Is using the $each the right way to go?

```
var search = [
  {
    "words":["hey", "bro"],
    "result":"Hey man!"
  },
  {
    "words":["ninja","stuff"],
    "result":"Other answer"
  }
];

var query = search.words;
var answer = search.result;

 $("#txt").keypress(function(e) {
   if(e.which == 13) {

    var str = $('#txt').val();

    var res = str.toLowerCase();

    if (query.some(function(v) { return res.indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
      $('#result').html(answer);
      }
    else {
      $('#result').html('Bummer man! You just don\'t yap about Hyper, why are you even here dawg? ');
    }
}

  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `search` is an array thus `search.words` and `search.result` will not work

Comment: @Weedoze we are well aware of that. We used to use `search[0].words` and the same for results. But that limits us to just display that specific line and not in general which is what we are looking for.

Comment: `var query = search.words;` wat. surely you want some kind of loop.

Comment: what if the input is `hey ninja man` ? would it answer `Hey man!` or `Other answer` or `either of the two` ?

Answer (score -1):

```js
var search = [{
  "words": ["hey", "bro"],
  "result": "Hey man!"
}, {
  "words": ["ninja", "stuff"],
  "result": "Other answer"
}];


$("#txt").keypress(function(e) {
  //Detect key *ENTER* pressed
  if (e.which == 13) {
    
    //Get the string entered and switch to lowercase
    var str = $('#txt').val().toLowerCase();
    //Init found to false
    var found = false;
    
    //Iterate each object of the arrat *search*
    $.each(search, function(index, value){
      //Check if the entered string is present in the array of words
      if(value.words.indexOf(str) !== -1){
        //We found the entered word
        found = true;
        //Display the result linked to the word entered
        $('#result').html(value.result);
        //Exit from the each() method
        return false;
      }
    });
    //Check if we found our word
    if(!found)
      //Display the error message if you dont find the entered word
      $('#result').html('Bummer man! You just don\'t yap about Hyper, why are you even here dawg? ');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt">

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: this works the way we want it. Thanks a lot! If you have any time we would much appreciate if you could insert comments describing each step.

Comment: @h.johan Done, tell me if you understand everything

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works partly as we want it to do. However, it only works if there is one keyword (in this case "hey" or "bro" works, not "Hey bro") which  eliminates the possibility to get a answer through a sentence (ex. "Could you say anything about ninjas?) @weedoze

Comment: @h.johan Oh ok that's why you downvoted the answer ? Do you want me to try to make it work like you want or are you doing it yourself ?

Comment: @h.johan What would be the result of a sentence like **hey bro, what do you think about ninjas ?** - The result would be **Hey man Other answer !** ?

Comment: good question @Weedoze coz there is a high chance that a user will combine those words in queries...

Comment: I haven't downvoted anything. Why would I downvote my own question? (have under 15 in reputation. My voting doesn't show) @Weedoze

Comment: @four & Weedoze: We have thought about that as well. In this case we just wanna make it possible to combine the keywords. Example: "Hey" and "bro" gives you "Hey man!" but combining them "Hey bro" gives you the "Bummer man..". It would be great to be able to combine them "Hey bro" also gives you the "Hey man!".

Comment: @h.johan What about the sentence : **hey bro, what do you think about ninjas ?**

Comment: @Weedoze Yes, that a though one. Is it possible to limit the possibility to search just the keyword for every section. Meaning within every `["hey", "bro"]` then the next one `["ninja", "stuff"]` to limit that error?

Comment: @h.johan i dont understand. Can you please just tell me what would be the output ?

Comment: @Weedoze If you type "Hey", "Bro" or combine them as "Hey bro" it should have the same output "Hey man!"

Comment: @h.johan My question is : What is the output if I type in *Hey bro, what do you think about ninjas ?* ?